# run typescript compiler from shell command - permission denied

Tags: macos, bash, shell, typescript

I'm using Parallels because I prefer the Mac OS but the work we do is all in Visual Studio.  We currently have a build.cmd batch file that builds our typescript files.  Because I'd prefer to work on the Mac side when I can, I thought I would rewrite the script in bash and to also get some experience writing a shell script.  I have a main `build.sh` command that runs the other shell scripts like `compile-templates.sh` and `compile-source.sh`.  I am trouble with the compile-source.sh portion now. Currently, the batch file looks like:

```
echo TypeScript Version:
CALL node_modules\.bin\tsc  -v
```

The typescript compiler is included in our Solution so we are all using the same one throughout the solution.  In my compile-source.sh, I try to do this:

```
node_modules/.bin/tsc -v
```

or this

```
./node_modules/.bin/tsc -v
```

And I get permission denied.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: check you file's execution permission

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several approaches to try. You can use bash to run the script like this:

```
bash node_modules/.bin/tsc -v
```

Or you can try to change the permissions on the file:

```
chmod a+x node_modules/.bin/tsc
```

This should enable you to run the script like this:

```
./node_modules/.bin/tsc -v
```

But in that case, make sure your script starts with a shebang line to tell the system it is a bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem after moving node_modules from one SSD to another.
Resolved with `rm -rf ./node_modules; npm i`